# Changing the RSS and Dynamic Views layout when using Blogger as a Podcast index

Tags: blogger, feedburner, podcast

I'm trying to set up a podcast service at present.

This is just a 'spare time' task - so I wanted a quick, easy way to do it.

To get this working:

- I've ripped (with owner permission) some YouTube content across to MP3 and hosted this content on Azure Blob Storage.
- I've posted blog posts - with linked mp3 content - inside a Blogger website.
- I've registered the RSS feed with iTunes

This all seems to be working OK - http://dotnetmobilepodcast.blogspot.co.uk/

However, when it comes to a couple of final touches, then I'm hitting problems.

#### RSS

I would like to add iTunes metadata to the RSS feed.

However, I can't find any way to do this inside the Blogger system.

To workaround this I've tried using FeedBurner with its StreamCast plugin.

However, the output from FeedBurner doesn't seem to be accepted by iTunes - e.g. http://feeds.feedburner.com/MobileAppCSharpPodcasts leads to this very unhelpful 11111 message:

[image: 11111]

Is there any other way I can get this iTunes metadata content into the Blogger RSS feed - e.g. maybe an alternative service or a Yahoo! Pipe?

#### Showing the MP3 files in the Blog

I'm trying to work out how to automatically display the linked enclosures inside the blog posts - do the blogger Dynamic Views don't seem to have any way of doing this? I've found the HTML in those views very difficult to follow.

If necessary I can workaround this using manual entries into each blog post... but I'd prefer to do this programatically if I can.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a valid feed to submit to iTunes. In your case, it seems that your feed has [some warning](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http://dotnetmobilepodcast.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss). Maybe, you can try to fix them (if you can).

Then, usually, iTunes is ok with Feedburner feed. But sometimes, iTunes is simply down for accepting new feed.

I have a podcast plateform for DJs, so I submit lots of feed to iTunes and when I got this error I contact them. Here is a the reply:

> We are experiencing a known submission error. We are working to resolve this asap and appreciate your patience.

Did you try only since yesterday? Just wait few hours/days and try again.

Comment: Thanks. I tried yesterday and again today - but I will wait and try again. I think the problem is in the feed somewhere... I haven't logged the problem into their support site as I can't get into it at the moment (they ask me to login, then insist on a new username, then complain that I already have a username... argh!). I think the only way to fix those warnings is to find an alternative to feedburner - hence the question here :)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Views have a number of limits on what you can show.

Why don't you just choose a Designer template instead?